# How can I use regex to remove /1 or /2?

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, regex-negation

Regex gurus,

Here is the following line of code I want to parse with regex:

```
@ERR030882.2595 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:3:1:6649:5175#0/1
```

I want to obtain the following:

```
@ERR030882.2595 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:3:1:6649:5175#0
```

I have written the following regex on rubular.com:

```
(@.* *.)(!?(\/.))
```

My idea is to use negation to remove /1 by `(!?(\/.))`. However, this produces the entire line?

```
@ERR030882.2595 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:3:1:6649:5175#0/1
```

Why is `(?!thisismystring)` not removing /1? I googled the fire out of this, but they seemed to suggest similar things I am already trying? I deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: Is `s#/\d+$##` not good enough?

Comment: a simple search and replace function would does this job. I donno why you need a negation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to write is `/(\@.* .*)(?=\/\d)/` (you need to escape the at sign `@` to prevent Perl from treating it as an array) but you need a *positive* look-ahead because you want to match everything up until the following characters are a slash followed by a digit.

Here is a program that demonstrates.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $s = '@ERR030882.2595 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:3:1:6649:5175#0/1';

$s =~ /(\@.* .*)(?=\/.)/;

print $1, "\n";
```

***But*** you would be much better off copying the whole string and removing the slash and everything after it, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = '@ERR030882.2595 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:3:1:6649:5175#0/1';

(my $fixed = $s) =~ s{/\d+$}{};

print $fixed, "\n";
```

**output**

```
@ERR030882.2595 HWI-BRUNOP16X_0001:3:1:6649:5175#0
```

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive and educational answer.